# Gerrit with Apache2 - The HTTP server did not provide the username in the Authorization header when it forwarded the request to Gerrit Code Review

Tags: apache, authentication, configuration, gerrit

I have problem with gerrit instalation with HTTP auth.

This is my gerrit.config:

```
[gerrit]
    basePath = git
    serverId = fee746a4-35f5-43e5-a39f-e2e77ce5bd7c
    canonicalWebUrl = http://127.0.0.1:9091/
[database]
    type = h2
    database = /home/mapa/gerrit_example/db/ReviewDB
[auth]
    type = HTTP
[receive]
    enableSignedPush = false
[sendemail]
    smtpServer = localhost
[container]
    user = root
    javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
[sshd]
    listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
    listenUrl = http://*:9090/
[cache]
    directory = cache
```

and my virtualhost config on apache:

```
Listen 9091
<VirtualHost *:9091>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    <Location /login/>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Gerrit Code Review"
        AuthBasicProvider file
        AuthUserFile /media/sf_shared/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
    AllowEncodedSlashes On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9090/
</VirtualHost>
```

All what I get is
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KPAP.png)

I have followed other tutorials and solutions for similar problems but with no result.

Comment: How do you access Gerrit then? Should be via port 9091

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Apache work on port 9091, and gerrit on canonicalWebUrl = http://127.0.0.1:9091/ (Apache and gerrit must work on diferent ports)

Your Apache redirect to ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9090/

try to use 
canonicalWebUrl = http://127.0.0.1:9090/

Comment: I have changed all IPs from 127.0.0.1 to IPs from local network and it works now, thanks.

Comment: Did you change port (from canonicalWebUrl = http://127.0.0.1:9091/ to canonicalWebUrl = http://127.0.0.1:9090/)? If you post your setting, it would more informative for other people. Please, make your answer, it would be interesting.

Comment: So, for now my apache is listening on port 80 and redirect to ProxyPass / https://192.168.0.185:8080/. CanonicalWebUrl is http://192.168.0.185:80 and I have access to gerrit via 192.168.0.185:80. ListenUrl in gerrit config changed to http://*:8080.